# How to Sniff signalR calls using chrome Developer Tools

Tags: signalr, google-chrome-devtools

I downloaded Jabbar chat website and ran it inside Chrome. I wanted to see what all is happening between the browser and server and for that checked the network tab. However, I see no entry in network tab (neither xHr nor websocket or anything else) but SignalR is working fine. It does send and receive messages. I wonder what is signalR using that developer tools cannot log. Is there a setting required in developer tools?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Nowadays when your signalR is using WebSockets it is a bit different. Starting with Chrome 58 you have to click on the **Network** tab and then activate the **WS** filter. There will be one entry when the signalR connection has been established. Now click on the **Frames** sub-tab. Here you see every message which has been received by the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You should turn on client-side logging so you know which transport type you're dealing with (`$.connection.hub.logging = true;`). In case of long-polling, you should see the XHR calls in the network tab. In case of a websocket connection, you should be able to see the frames when choosing the "WebSockets" filter on the bottom, then clicking on the connection entry, then selecting the "Frames" tab. This won't auto-refresh, unfortunately, so you'll have to click on the connection entry in the left whenever you need an update.

If that's not good enough, you'll probably have to look elsewhere (Wireshark, Fiddler, etc.)